# How to disable sundays from jquery datetimepicker?

Tags: jquery, datetimepicker

I am working on jquery datetimepicker and I want to disable Sundays from datetimepicker how can I do that?

This is my jquery code:

```
 $(".datetimepicker").datetimepicker({ format: 'm-d-Y H:i', defaultDate: new Date(),
    minDate: '-1970/01/6',
    maxDate: 0,
    closeOnDateSelect:true

    });
```

Comment: Which one are you using? What did you find when you looked at its documentation?

Comment: i am using bootstrap datetimepicker

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add this attribute `daysOfWeekDisabled: [0],` to the JavaScript.`0` inside the array brackets indicates `Sunday`.If you want to disable any other days of a week, include inside the array as [0,6] for Sundays and Saturdays.

Comment: Thanx Hazard For Your reply.but its not working..i did the same thing..but its not getting disabled..

Comment: Which `datetimepicker` you are using ?

Comment: am using bootstrap.js datetimepicker..i tried the code which you provide me..but still its not working..this is  my new code..but here am not getting the default date,,and sunday is not getting disabled..

Comment: $(".datetimepicker").datetimepicker({ format: 'm-d-Y H:i',
           
            defaultDate:new Date(),
            daysOfWeekDisabled: [0],
            timepicker: false,
            minDate: '-1970/01/6',
            maxDate: 0,
            closeOnDateSelect: true

        });

Comment: go through [this](http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/) link and use correct formats

Answer (score 1):

First of all update your datetimepicker library .

https://plugins.jquery.com/datetimepicker/

then click on 'download now' then extract Zip Folder then open folder click build then select jquery.datetimepicker.full.js  file and jquery.datetimepicker.min.css  copy both and past on your project according  to use library path.

Then use this code in jQuery...

```
jQuery('#Your Id').datetimepicker({
        format : 'd/m/Y',
        changeMonth : false,
        changeYear : false,
        timepicker : false,
        closeOnDateSelect : true,
        scrollInput : false,
        minDate : 0,
        disabledWeekDays:[0]
});
```